# Generators and files

Tags: python, generator, operator-precedence, generator-expression

When I write:

```
lines = (line.strip() for line in open('a_file'))
```

Is the file opened immediately or is the file system only accessed when I start to *consume* the generator expression?

Comment: If you do `open = print` first, then your code does print `a_file`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann It took me a while but at least I understood your comment... Thank you very much

Comment: @MSeifert Very nice edit!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`open()` is called immediately upon the construction of the generator, irrespective of when or whether you consume from it.

The relevant spec is [PEP-289](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/#early-binding-versus-late-binding):

> **Early Binding versus Late Binding**
>
> After much discussion, it was
>   decided that the first (outermost) for-expression should be evaluated
>   immediately and that the remaining expressions be evaluated when the
>   generator is executed.
>
> Asked to summarize the reasoning for binding the first expression,
>   Guido offered [5]:
>
> *Consider `sum(x for x in foo())`. Now suppose there's a bug in `foo()`
>   that raises an exception, and a bug in `sum()` that raises an exception
>   before it starts iterating over its argument. Which exception would
>   you expect to see? I'd be surprised if the one in `sum()` was raised
>   rather the one in `foo()`, since the call to `foo()` is part of the
>   argument to `sum()`, and I expect arguments to be processed before the
>   function is called.*
>
> *OTOH, in `sum(bar(x) for x in foo())`, where `sum()` and `foo()` are
>   bugfree, but `bar()` raises an exception, we have no choice but to delay
>   the call to `bar()` until `sum()` starts iterating -- that's part of the
>   contract of generators. (They do nothing until their `next()` method is
>   first called.)*

See the rest of that section for further discussion.

Answer (score 6):

It is opened immediately. You can verify this if you use a filename that's not present (it will throw an Exception which indicates that Python actually tried to open it immediatly).

You can also use a function that gives more feedback to see that the command is executed even before the generator is iterated over:

```
def somefunction(filename):
    print(filename)
    return open(filename)

lines = (line.strip() for line in somefunction('a_file'))  # prints
```

However if you use a generator function instead of a generator expression the file is only opened when you iterate over it:

```
def somefunction(filename):
    print(filename)
    for line in open(filename):
        yield line.strip()

lines = somefunction('a_file')  # no print!

list(lines)                     # prints because list iterates over the generator function.
```

Comment: I appreciate your observation about the difference between generator expressions vs generator functions.  I've not approved your answer because I prefer [the one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45758642/2749397) referencing the original decision process, but yours is a very good one!

Answer (score 2):

It is opened immediately.

Example:

```
def func():
    print('x')
    return [1, 2, 3]

g = (x for x in func())
```

Output:

```
x
```

The function needs to return an iterable object.
`open()` returns an open file object that is iterable.
Therefore, the file will be opened when you define the generator expression.